# Combine two dropdown menus to determine submit button link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submit, dropdown

I have two dropdown menus.  The first is to choose your location.  The second is to choose what type of pictures you want to upload.  (i.e. Option 1 - Akron, Option 2 - Skyline).  I've setup a file request (DropBox generated upload link) in my DropBox account for these options (Akron, Skyline).  If they choose (Akron, Houses), it'd be a different upload link.  Similarly, (Cleveland, Streets) would be yet another upload link.  Using JQuery, I have the link sent to my submit button HTML.  Everything I've tried sends to that link no matter what options I choose.  (i.e. everything goes to (Akron, Skyline) link even if I choose (Akron, Houses).  There is something wrong in my if statement and I can't figure it out.  Here is a sample of my code.  The if statement is for the (Akron, Skyline) combination.  Additional code will be written for other options once I get this one to work.  I've replaced the upload link with a generic URL.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
            <p> Choose Your Location </p>
            <select id="Location Select">
                <option value="Choose Location">Choose Location</option>
                <option value="Akron">Akron</option>
                <option value="Alliance">Alliance</option>
                <option value="Ashland">Ashland</option>
                <option value="Barberton">Barberton</option>
                <option value="Bellaire">Bellaire</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p> What Pictures or Videos are You Uploading? </p>
            <select id="Type Select">
                <option value="Choose Type">Choose Type</option>
                <option value="Skyline">Skyline</option>
                <option value="Streets">Streets</option>
                <option value="Houses">Houses</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href='URL'>
                <input type="button" value="Upload" />
                <script>
       if("#Location Select").val("Akron") && ("#Type  Select").val("Skyline"){
       $("a").attr("href",'https://www.google.com');
     }
     </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This this code. It was missing `$` as well as brackets.

```js
if($("#Location Select").val("Akron") && $("#Type  Select").val("Skyline")){
       $("a").attr("href",'https://www.google.com');
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
            <p> Choose Your Location </p>
            <select id="Location Select">
                <option value="Choose Location">Choose Location</option>
                <option value="Akron">Akron</option>
                <option value="Alliance">Alliance</option>
                <option value="Ashland">Ashland</option>
                <option value="Barberton">Barberton</option>
                <option value="Bellaire">Bellaire</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p> What Pictures or Videos are You Uploading? </p>
            <select id="Type Select">
                <option value="Choose Type">Choose Type</option>
                <option value="Skyline">Skyline</option>
                <option value="Streets">Streets</option>
                <option value="Houses">Houses</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href='URL'>
                <input type="button" value="Upload" />

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Both of the answers helped me get the result I needed!  Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Note

http://api.jquery.com/val/

.val() does not accept any arguments.

Also note that you first have to identify the selected element, and then get its value.

HTML IDs should not have spaces, and there should only be one ID of a particular string in any given document. If you want to describe a *type* of element, use `class` instead. For example:

```
<p> Choose Your Location </p>
<select class="Select" id="Location">
  <option value="Choose Location">Choose Location</option>
  <option value="Akron">Akron</option>
  <option value="Alliance">Alliance</option>
  <option value="Ashland">Ashland</option>
  <option value="Barberton">Barberton</option>
  <option value="Bellaire">Bellaire</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<p> What Pictures or Videos are You Uploading? </p>
<select class="Select" id="Type">
  <option value="Choose Type">Choose Type</option>
  <option value="Skyline">Skyline</option>
  <option value="Streets">Streets</option>
  <option value="Houses">Houses</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<a href='URL'>
  <input type="button" value="Upload" />

<script>
$('input').click((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const location = $('#Location')[0];
  const type = $('#Type')[0];
  const locationVal = location.options[location.selectedIndex].value;
  const typeVal = type.options[type.selectedIndex].value;
  if (locationVal === 'Akron' && typeVal === 'Skyline') {
    console.log('Akron/Skyline');
  } else {
    console.log(`Other, ${locationVal} ${typeVal}`);
  }
});
</script>
```

(you don't actually need the `class="Select"` here at all, based on the code so far)

Comment: Thanks!  Both of the answers helped me get the result I needed!  Really appreciate your help!